# Erro no Xcode após atualização para versão 11

Tags: ios, react, react-native, xcode

Desde que minha versão do Xcode atualizou não consigo mais rodar nenhum dos projetos que implementei,

Abaixo o está o print do meu problema, desde que o Xcode se atualizou automaticamente para versão 11 venho enfretando esse problema.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tentou com a versão do emulador mais recente(iphone 11)?

Answer (score 0):

Muda o modo de Build para o modo legacy:
- Vai em File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System: Legacy Build System.
Boa sorte.